# Query Active Directory via PowerShell script to get attributes for users in a csv file

Tags: powershell

I am new to the PowerShell. I have a csv file which has info about the login ids for a set of users. I need a PowerShell script that can take input from this csv file and query AD for custom attribute 5, last name and first name. Thank you all for your assistance.

Thanks,

Comment: I tried to write a code, however when I ran it, it gave me all the non-required info instead of just the info needed. I turned off the option of default values too. However, making it short here. I do not see append option in my power gui. is there a way to fix that? If this is fixed then I am all set. Thanks a lot guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Learn basic PowerShell. Ex. read [PowerShell Tutorial for beginners](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/). Chapter-menu on the right side, and skip the last ActiveDirectory part. You should rather use the official Active Directory module that's installed on DCs and available for servers and clients(install RSAT), or [Quest ActiveRoles module](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).
2. Import data using [Import-CSV](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx).
3. Query AD using Active Directory module.. [Get-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx).